# CefSharp: fonts look blurry and choppy

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp in a WPF project. I'm compiling from the source code, not nuget package (I know that's not recommended).

My problem is that when the browser control is scaled, text looks really bad: choppy, blurry, with very bad anti aliasing.

I've already tried setting

```
BrowserSettings.OffScreenTransparentBackground = false;
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
```

I also tried adding `subpixel-antialiased` as described [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/11013).

But all of this did not work. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Change the bitmapscalingmode

Comment: VERY INTERESTING! I will test this soon

Comment: Well, this improved the situation quite a lot, but things now look a little soft compared to other fonts. Still much, much better. Thank you.

Comment: Browser renders as an image, best to avoid scaling it directly, zooming in and out will give a better result.